# Remove previous data when executing AJAX request multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with ajax calling. It works correct except one thing, when I try to get data with the same option more than one times returns the new response but also still return the data of the previous response.

I think that there is something that I've missed.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').on('change', function () {
            var $optionValue = $('#loading-thing-post option:selected').text();
            var $categoryID = $('#loading-thing-post').val();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'http://localhost/visitingcy/public/management/getThingPost/' + $categoryID
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                    $('#thing-table').show();
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        index += 1;
                        var result = $('<tr>' +
                                '<td>' + index + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + value.title + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + value.category_name + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>');
                        $('tbody#thing-content').append(result);
                    })
                } else {
                    $('#thing-table').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: If the previous data is coming back in the response then you need to amend your server code. If you want to remove the previous data in the UI, call `empty()` on the containing element before you `append(result)`

Comment: first off and on the change event like this $('select').off('change').on('change', function () {

Comment: @JqueryKing ... why?

Comment: I thought the ajax call runs multiple times on change

Comment: It would appear not as the event is only bound once.

Comment: the change event is triggered only when different option is selected, so obviously the ajax call is triggered with different option value not with same option value. in fact the select event handler itself is not called when same option in selected.

Comment: Thank you # Rory McCrossan I've solved the problem. Post it as an answer if you want!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the content of #thing-content before each loop

```
                 $('tbody#thing-content').empty();
                 $('#thing-table').show();
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        index += 1;
                        var result = $('<tr>' +
                                '<td>' + index + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + value.title + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + value.category_name + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>');
                        $('tbody#thing-content').append(result);
                    })
```

Comment: Another simple way to proceed as $('tbody#thing-content').html(result); instead of append

Comment: @JqueryKing: Not inside a loop you dont :)

Comment: if you use .html(result) inside loop,you will loss previous iteration data.so you have to append  inside and remove before the loop.

Comment: @PavanTeja: It is actually *a lot* more efficient to concatenate one large string, with all the results, and replace that once only outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `abort` method to prevent old ajax results like this:

```
var ajaxSent;

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').on('change', function () {
            if(ajaxSent){
               ajaxSent.abort();
            }
            var $optionValue = $('#loading-thing-post option:selected').text();
            var $categoryID = $('#loading-thing-post').val();
            ajaxSent = $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'http://localhost/visitingcy/public/management/getThingPost/' + $categoryID
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                    $('#thing-table').show();
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        index += 1;
                        var result = $('<tr>' +
                                '<td>' + index + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + value.title + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + value.category_name + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>');
                        $('tbody#thing-content').append(result);
                    })
                } else {
                    $('#thing-table').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```